# React.js and jsx over ejs?

Tags: ejs, reactjs

What do react.js and jsx respectively allow you to do that ejs doesn't?
For what use cases would one employ one or the other. Are they mutually exclusive? Can they be used in combination?

Answer (score 24):

JSX and EJS are indeed both templating languages, however that's sort of where the similarities end. JSX is Facebook's offering to the JS world to make writing views with your React components simpler and more efficient ([you can learn more about JSX here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)).

To answer your questions in order:

1. ReactDOM, React and the JSX templating language are a suite of tools to make writing javascript view code more pleasant and more performant by using a complex difference engine to calculate when DOM reflows are necessary. EJS is similar to the JSX part of this equation, but cannot talk to your React components.
2. You would use JSX to write what your React components should return to the DOM in a friendlier, more readable way then what would be ordinarily written.
3. They *could* be used in combination, but it would be a long, pointless, up-hill battle to get them to talk to one another not to mention you would have to build a translator to get the EJS templates to be understood by React and ReactDOM. I wouldn't try it.

I assume you're embarking on your React journey... Welcome! At first things will be confusing, but keep digging. Once you get the basics, React development is a lot of fun and there's a great community surrounding the libraries.

Comment: I suppose I don't know enough about react(and in particular its component system?) to formulate the question. I'm familiar with Angular's component system. As yet I don't see why ejs and and react can't work together, and it's still not quite clear to me from your answer.

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull I am thinking the same. I think jsx on backend is overkill slowing down the dev due to webpack having to build more files. Or am I wrong? I went with ejs for backend just like the old good Angular.

Comment: I don't think React is hard to be used in combination with ejs. You can use ejs for simple html rendering and append a React app to any complex component or heavy js feature in the web app without much trouble with Babel,